# Setting timeout on selenium webdriver.PhantomJS

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

***The situation***

I have a simple python script to get the HTML source for a given url:

```
    browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
    browser.get(url)
    content = browser.page_source
```

Occasionally, the url points to a page with slow-loading external resources (e.g. video files, or really slow advertising content).

Webdriver will wait until those resources are loaded before completing the `.get(url)` request.

Note: For extraneous reasons, I need to do this with PhantomJS rather than `requests` or `urllib2`

---

***The question***

I'd like to set a timeout on PhantomJS resource loading so that if the resource is taking too long to load, the browser just assumes it doesn't exist or whatever.

This would allow me to perform the subsequent `.pagesource` query based on what the browser has loaded.

[Documentation](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/webdriver_phantomjs/selenium.webdriver.phantomjs.webdriver.html) on webdriver.PhantomJS is very thin, and I haven't found a similar question on SO.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

PhantomJS has provided `resourceTimeout`, which might suit your needs. I quote from documentation [here](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/settings.html)

> (in milli-secs) defines the timeout after which any resource requested
>   will stop trying and proceed with other parts of the page.
>   onResourceTimeout callback will be called on timeout.

So in Ruby, you can do something like

```ruby
require 'selenium-webdriver'

capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.phantomjs("phantomjs.page.settings.resourceTimeout" => "5000")
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :phantomjs, :desired_capabilities => capabilities
```

I believe in Python, it's something like (untested, only provides the logic, you are the Python developer, hopefully you will figure out)

```python
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities={'phantomjs.page.settings.resourceTimeout': '5000'})
```

Comment: Great answer! I hadn't figured out how to configure PhantomJS using desired_capabilities, so this  not only addresses my question but shows more broadly how to configure PhantomJS using the API reference you provided.

Comment: I'm setting this and still seeing resource timeouts -- this is with selenium (via python) and phantomjs 1.9.7.

Comment: I'm trying to get this working on Python too Adam. not many know. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23177659/how-to-set-timeout-for-phantomjs/23180327?noredirect=1

Answer (score 17):

Long Explanation below, so **TLDR**:

**Current version of Selenium's Ghostdriver (in PhantomJS 1.9.8) ignores resourceTimeout option, use webdriver's implicitly_wait(), set_page_load_timeout() and wrap them under try-except block.**

```python
#Python
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
browser.implicitly_wait(3)
browser.set_page_load_timeout(3)
try:
    browser.get("http://url_here")
except TimeoutException as e:
    #Handle your exception here
    print(e)
finally:
    browser.quit()
```

---

**Explanation**

To provide PhantomJS [page settings](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/settings.html) to Selenium, one can use webdriver's DesiredCapabilities such as:

```python
#Python
from selenium import webdriver
cap = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS
cap["phantomjs.page.settings.resourceTimeout"] = 1000
cap["phantomjs.page.settings.loadImages"] = False
cap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = "faking it"
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities=cap)
```

```java
//Java
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.phantomjs();
capabilities.setCapability("phantomjs.page.settings.resourceTimeout", 1000);
capabilities.setCapability("phantomjs.page.settings.loadImages", false);
capabilities.setCapability("phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent", "faking it");
WebDriver webdriver = new PhantomJSDriver(capabilities);
```

**But, here's the catch: As in today (2014/Dec/11) with PhantomJS 1.9.8 and its embedded Ghostdriver, resourceTimeout won't be applied by Ghostdriver ([See the Ghostdriver issue#380 in Github](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/issues/380)).**

For a workaround, simply use Selenium's timeout functions/methods and wrap webdriver's get method in a try-except/try-catch block, e.g.

```python
#Python
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
browser.implicitly_wait(3)
browser.set_page_load_timeout(3)
try:
    browser.get("http://url_here")
except TimeoutException as e:
    #Handle your exception here
    print(e)
finally:
    browser.quit()
```

```java
//Java
WebDriver webdriver = new PhantomJSDriver();
webdriver.manage().timeouts()
        .pageLoadTimeout(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
try {
    webdriver.get("http://url_here");
} catch (org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException e) {
    //Handle your exception here
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
} finally {
    webdriver.quit();
}
```

Comment: Confirmed issue still happening 7/14/2017, which means it will not likely ever be fixed.  PhantomJs ver 2.1.1 Selenium 3.4.3.  However, set_page_load_timeout works charmingly.